# Deploying report shows an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 for my reports.

I have been working in my local environment and there was no problem with deploying to the local server. Now I want to deploy all the reports to live server but when I try to deploy to the live server by changing the Target server url and then providing the user name and password. its showing the error. (I'm deploying from VS 2008)

```
===================================

Could not connect to the report server http://192.168.0.217/ReportServer. Verify that the TargetServerURL is valid and that you have the correct permissions to connect to the report server. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer)

===================================

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. (System.Web.Services)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2006.ReportServiceAuthentication.GetAuthenticationMode()
   at ReportServiceClient2010.CheckAuthenticated()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.DetectEndpointAndAuthenticate(String url, ICredentials credentials, String& authCookieName, Cookie& authCookie, EndpointType& endpointType)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.DetectEndpointAndAuthenticate(String url, ConnectionProperties& connectionProperties)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.GetCredentials(String url, CancelFlag cancelFlag)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportProjectDeployer.PrepareDeploy()

===================================

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (System)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

===================================

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (System)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

But Im able to browse the report server from my local machine by providing the credentials. Anyone knowsa solution for this?

Comment: is 192.168.0.217 really your live server, may be it is but its worth to check the IP. Did you check if the port is blocked?

Comment: I have been deploying to both live server and my ST. and this is a sample IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , should help mostly. Also try and see if you are able to upload reports one by one using the Upload facility on the SSRS server itself
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1135602-150-1.aspx#bm1135709

Comment: This worked for my ST, now trying in live server. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, When I tried this in my live server it didn't worked. There the port number was 8080. and now it shows the same error

Comment: is your Live Server in the same domain as your ST server? Also, did you try to upload the SSRS report using the SSRS server itself rather than using VS 2008.

Comment: No our ST is in our network and live server is in another domain. How can I upload SSRS report using SSRS server itself?